# blogger_blog.comments.latest_comment_limit error in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

While trying out the Symfony2 blog tutorial I get this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The parameter "blogger_blog.comments.latest_comment_limit" must be defined.")
```

Even though it is defined in `config.yml` as

```
parameters:
    # Blogger max latest comments
    blogger_blog.comments.latest_comment_limit: 10
```

Comment: The error should have given a line number in the twig template, can you provide that section of code as well?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have "    - { resource: @BloggerBlogBundle/Resources/config/config.yml }" included in your config.yml in apps/config. This should fix the problem.